# Differences in IAM Role Usage Between EC2 Instance and AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli, identity-management

I can connect to an ec2 instance in 2 ways:

1. via SSH
2. using the accessKey, secretKey, token and region via AWS CLI on my personal machine

When I run **aws sts get-caller-identity** (using the accessKey, secretKey, token FROM the ec2 instance via SSH), I get a slightly different userId, and assumed-role within the ARN. Attached below is an example:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity via SSH  
{  
    "UserId": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:i-0b999999999999999",    
    "Account": "739214605182",    
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::739214605182:assumed-role/Test-Role-Ec2/i-0b999999999999999"
}  
  
  
  
aws sts get-caller-identity via AWS CLI  
{  
    "UserId": "BBBBBBBBBBBB:aws:ec2-instance:i-0b999999999999999",    
    "Account": "739214605182",    
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::739214605182:assumed-role/aws:ec2-instance/i-0b999999999999999"
}
```

It seems like the AWS CLI is using my account credentials, while the ec2 instance is using the IAM Role I designated - which is Test-Role-Ec2

Is it possible for AWS CLI to have the **Test-Role-Ec2** IAM Role set?

I thought that if I imported the access key secret key and token, that I would assume the same role (Test-Role-EC2), despite being on AWS CLI.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the AWS CLI tool on your local machine, you are **not** connecting to the EC2 instance. You are connecting directly to the public AWS API from your local computer. The EC2 instance is not involved in any way with the AWS API calls you make from your local computer.

> I thought that if I imported the access key secret key and token, that I would assume the same role (Test-Role-EC2), despite being on AWS CLI.

No, that is an incorrect assumption. Your assumption that the EC2 instance is in any way involved in this process is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Is there any way for me to set the IAM Role Test-Role-EC2 when I use the public AWS API? So instead of: assumed-role/aws:ec2-instance/, Id like to see: assumed-role/Test-Role-Ec2/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use an EC2 instance role on your local computer. Those only work with EC2 instances. It's really unclear why you care about this. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm learning about security misconfigurations in cloud environments, in this case, AWS IMDSv1 service. Exploiting SSRF on an AWS Env. with IMDSv1 configured allows one to extract the AWS keys. I'm asking these questions because I'm in the process of creating my own vulnerable environment for security research.

Comment: IMDSv1 (Instance Metadata Service v1) is only accessible from inside the EC2 instance itself. Running code on your local computer to access the AWS API will have no ability to interact with the IMDSv1 service. You are still confusing the EC2 server (a virtual machine) with the entire AWS cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be related to how you're querying the IMDSv1 within the EC2 instance. The second ARN you're getting (from the AWS CLI) looks to be the role for a generic EC2 instance. I can get a similar value by querying the following endpoint, importing the keys outside the instance, and running get-caller-identity:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance
```

Instead start by querying the IAM info:

```
$> curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info
{
"Code" : "Success",
"LastUpdated" : "2023-12-14T16:00:00Z",
"InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:instance-profile/<rolename>",
"InstanceProfileId" : "<profileID>"
}
```

That Profile ARN should give you the role name you're looking for. Use that to query the role's access keys:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<rolename>
```

(As a side note: you may want to redact your account ID. They're not *techincally* sensitive, but they do open you up to some enumeration and console login attacks)